# How to stop systemd oneshot from running when file has not changed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, certificate, systemd

I have created a systemd service to restart some docker containers when their SSL certificate is renewed. I created this unit file, so that my script to restart the containers is executed when service detects that the certificate has changed:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/mailcow-cert-restart/mailcow-cert-restart.sh
Description=Restarts affected mailcow containers when their certificates are renewed by nginx-proxy-manager

[Path]
PathChanged=/opt/compose-stacks/mailcow-dockerized/data/assets/ssl/cert.pem

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that when the service is restarted with `systemctl restart myservice` it restarts the docker containers even though the certificate hasn't been changed since. Is there any way to ensure that the script will **only** be run when the certificate file changes? I don't really want these containers being restarted unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

`[Path]` certainly doesn't work this way. For one, it only works in `.path` units – you cannot put it in other unit types. Second, its mechanism is exactly the opposite of what you want – it doesn't prevent anything from happening and does not keep persistent state; the purpose of PathChanged= is to *trigger events* that cause a service to be started.

What you want is best done within the service's script/program – store a timestamp (e.g. "touch" a marker file) whenever an update is done; compare the stored timestamp with that of `cert.pem`.

For example, in just a few lines of bash:

```bash
if [[ cert.pem -nt /opt/.mailcow.lastupd ]]; then
    <restart stuff> &&
    touch /opt/.mailcow.lastupd
fi
```

This could also be done as a `ConditionExec` (I was going to write `/bin/sh -c "[ ... ]"` at first, but `[` aka `test` does exist as a standalone program):

```ini
[Unit]
ConditionExec=/bin/[ /opt/foo/cert.pem -nt /etc/dovecot/cert.pem ]
```